# What would be the best approach to enable data access to millions of records in an open source fashion?

Tags: architecture, database-design, sql

We're currently building a Django app that's a doctor-patient-agent manager that allows patients to book a consultation, and doctors give them their prescription and information. What's important is that we're handling sensitive data, and we're planning on open sourcing some of the data (which we will be anonymized of course, and will eventually have millions and millions of data) so people can perform data analysis into them.

We're currently working out on storing, deploying, and showing the information on a PostgresSQL database and hosted on Google Cloud.

So these are the concerns:

- How can we allow users to retrieve millions of rows? Through a REST endpoint? (This seems unplausible if you were to get millions of records). Can they connect directly to a database through a manager such MS SQSS? Or should we provide a precompiled (yet stale) .h5 file that could be downloaded from Google Storage?
- Should we have separate databases? A database for the open source and the other one that is consumed by the app? Or will some user permissions suffice? What about availability? What if the schema changes?
- What is the best way for us to give access to the users and how can we achieve this? If it's a REST endpoint, the JWT signed with a client/secret id combo but again, we're very limited on the amount of data.
- Should we use Hadoop for whatever reason or something similar?
- How could we visualize the aggregate data efficiently? Should we make a store procedure that currently aggregates the data as soon as it comes in and then display the result?

Comment: [How to handle a question that asks many things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267059/839601)

Comment: This could be incredibly dangerous. If you need to ask how to built a system to safely provide anonymized data, then you're almost certainly not a good candidate to implement a system to anonymized data. Nothing personal, I'm not either. Anonymizing data correctly, in a way where statistical analysis can't be used to de-anonymize large parts of the "unknowns", is incredibly mathematically complicated. You would absolutely need a separate database (or table, at least). Merely subsetting (e.g. omit the name field) your data isn't anonymizing it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy

Comment: If you do go for a REST API, then it's probably worth looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Healthcare_Interoperability_Resources which is the industry standard for sharing this sort of data.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica - but no part of this question asks *how to anonymize* the data. That was entirely out of scope, and the question simply asks how to expose the anonymized data to possible consumers.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan It hints at it, and I'm just reading between the lines. Consider this quote: "Should we have separate databases? A database for the open source and the other one that is consumed by the app? Or will some user permissions suffice?" That presupposes that perhaps all it takes to produce an anonymous dataset is to provide a subset view on the full dataset, with access control blocking access to the full data. That is entirely off the mark. All the values need to be fuzzed. Knowing that definitely rules out sharing a DB as a live option.

Comment: I agree, and I'll add a point to my answer to that effect.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Thank you for the input. As a matter of fact, we hadn't gone that deep in the thinking process. Thanks for raising that concern. We initially thought of providing a separate table with the processed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have two different datasets here - the first one is your operational database with the private information, and the second is the anonymized dataset that isn't actually used by your app, but is just a secondary product you want to put out there so people can use, but don't really want to *support*, right?

Before we go into how to share the anonymized data, I'll stress an important point - a system containing confidential medical data is, well, *confidential*, and one of the basic tenets of information security is that confidential and non-confidential data should *not* coexist in the same place. If you store both your confidential data and a REST API for your non-confidential data on the same server and in tables in the same database, you can might as well assume that your non-confidential users will access your confidential data. Those two systems must be completely separate.

Back to the matter at hand: Consider the fact that you really don't need to be hosting a dynamic API or database for this data. You don't know who will use it and for what. Will they require querying it repeatedly, causing your servers a lot of CPU and traffic? Do they need to transform it or enrich it, meaning they will need to export their own copy anyway?

Unless you want to control what they can do with it (which kinda goes against the open-source concept), you might consider doing what IMDB does with their openly accessible dumps of [multi-million-row movie/tv/actor datasets](https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/), which are just that - datasets stored as simple TSV files that are updated nightly and can be copied locally, and stored, accessed, manipulated or enriched by anyone with you having to host this data for them.

There are two "products" here. The first is the data, the second is a service for easily accessing, querying, filtering and manipulating it. The former is (presumably) your value-add specialty that differentiates you from other datasets. You probably neither want nor are able to shine in the latter, so don't bother - give out the data and let people use it themselves.